# to change entries inside a column (time) in a large database

Tags: mysql

I fetched some time data from a source (below listed), and want to convert it.

```
060000
061500
063000
064500
070000
071500
073000
```

From

```
6:360:00
6:375:00
6:390:00
6:405:00
7:420:00
7:435:00
7:450:00
7:465:00
8:480:00
8:495:00
```

Comment: What the columns database something like VARCHAR or CHAR? Besides both formats are really bad for storing a time.. You should make the column a time datatype and store the time as `06:00:00` for example.

Comment: for this I have to convert first my column in mysql, which is i dont know how to

Answer (score 0):

The rules for the conversion aren't clear. It looks like we want to implement some sort of conversion

```
 from          to 
 ---------    ----
 6:360:00  -> 060000
 6:375:00  -> 061500
 6:390:00  -> 063000
 6:405:00  -> 064500
 7:420:00  -> 070000
 7:435:00  -> 071500
 7:450:00  -> 073000
```

---

Looks like there's a need to split the original string into three parts.

SQL isn't the best tool for parsing strings, but we can hack something together.

Assuming that all values contain two colon characters, we could do something like this (using a user-defined variable here, in place of a column name)

```
SET @foo := '6:375:00';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@foo,':',1)                          AS p1
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@foo,':',2),':',-1)  AS p2
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(@foo,':',-1)                         AS p3
```

we get

```
p1     p2    p3
-----  ----  ----
6      375   00
```

It appers that we need to do some kind of arithmetic. Do we take the part before the first colon (p1) and use that as "hour"?

The second part (between the colons) appears to possibly be a number of minutes since midnight.  We could do a modulo 60 operation and get the remainder, and use that as a number of minutes. (We could also use the result of the integer division by sixty, and use that as "hour".

We can add zero to each part, to get those converted to numbers, and then we can format each part as a string of two digits with leading zeros. And then concatenate the parts back into a single string.

```
SELECT v.foo
     , CONCAT( RIGHT(CONCAT('00',  v.p1 + 0        ),2)
             , RIGHT(CONCAT('00', (v.p2 + 0) MOD 60),2) 
             , RIGHT(CONCAT('00',  v.p3 +0         ),2)
       ) AS bar
  FROM (
         SELECT @foo                                                 AS foo
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(@foo,':',1)                          AS p1
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@foo,':',2),':',-1)  AS p2
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(@foo,':',-1)                         AS p3
       ) v
```

---

To use these operations against the column of a table, replace the three occurrences of `@foo` with a valid column name, and add a `FROM` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT v.foo
     , CONCAT( RIGHT(CONCAT('00',  v.p1 + 0        ),2)
             , RIGHT(CONCAT('00', (v.p2 + 0) MOD 60),2) 
             , RIGHT(CONCAT('00',  v.p3 +0         ),2)
       ) AS bar
  FROM (
         SELECT t.foo                                                 AS foo
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,':',1)                          AS p1
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,':',2),':',-1)  AS p2
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.foo,':',-1)                         AS p3
           FROM my_table t
       ) v
```

---

The conversion falls apart when source `foo` values don't contain two colon characters.

Not at all clear what we want to do with the converted value.  (If this is a "time" value, I would tend to convert the value to `TIME` datatype, rather than a character string.